# Overriding vals in Scala

Tags: scala, polymorphism, overriding

I have tried to override val in Scala as this:

```
trait T{
  val str: String
}

sealed abstract class Test extends T{
  val str: String = "str"
}

class Test1 extends Test{
  val str = super.str + "test1" //super may not be used on value str
}
```

But this refused to compile. Why? I wanted to override value in the abstract class using the abstract class's value itself. How to do this?

In my particular case I ***cannot*** pass it as a class parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala compiler does not allow to use super on a `val`. If you are not caring about re-evaluation, you can just use `def` instead.

```
trait T{
  def str: String
}

sealed abstract class Test extends T{
  def str: String = "str"
}

class Test1 extends Test{
  def str = super.str + "test1" //super may not be used on value str
}

defined trait T
defined class Test
defined class Test1
```

Comment: I agree with this, but you didn't change OP's code. :) `T` should have `def str`, `Test` should have `def str`, and `Test1` should have `override def str`.

Answer (score 4):

If you *do* care about it avoiding repeated initialization, you can extract it into a method:

```
sealed abstract class Test extends T {
  lazy val str: String = initStr

  protected def initStr = "str"
}

class Test1 extends Test{
  override protected def initStr = super.initStr + "test1"
}
```

You can also make `str` non-`lazy`, but it's all to easy to end up with initialization order problems that way.