# Scala : Why can't we do super.val?

Tags: scala, overriding, instance, member

I am practicing this code from JavaTpoint for learning inheritance in Scala. But I cannot access the member Bike from the class Vehicle who's value is initialized to zero. I tried by super type reference but it still shows the overridden value. Why does it not allow to access the super class field and directs to the overridden sub class field (speed) . here is the code and the output.
Thanking in advance.

```scala
class Vehicle {
  val speed = 0
  println("In vehicle constructor " +speed)
  def run() {
    println(s"vehicle is running at $speed")
  }
}

class Bike extends Vehicle {
  override val speed = 100
  override def run() {
    super.run()
    println(s"Bike is running at $speed km/hr")
  }
}

object MainObject3 {
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    var b = new Bike()
    b.run()
    var v = new Vehicle()
    v.run()
    var ve:Vehicle=new Bike()
    println("SuperType reference" + ve.speed)
    ve.run()
  }
}
```

[image: How do I get the result using instance of Bike.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we know, after **Scala** compile, **Scala** will be transfered to **Java bytecode**, it's for compatible with **JVM**.

And for the class `Vehicle` variable `val speed`, after compile it's visible for it's subclass `Bike`(the `protected` variable), we can view the `bytecode` of `Vehicle`:

```
  public Vehicle();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #63                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: bipush        10
       7: putfield      #13                 // Field speed:I
      10: return
```

As we can see, it's init the `speed`'s value **10** in the `Vehicle` constructor method.

and we also can find the init action in `Bike` constructor method:

```
  public Bike();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #67                 // Method Vehicle."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: bipush        100
       7: putfield      #13                 // Field speed:I
      10: return
```

it's setting `100` for `speed` in constructor method.

so when `init` the `Bike` object, the `speed` field's value has been updated to `100` in the `superclass` `Vehicle`. so `super.val` will not make sense in there.

and there is another thing need to call out: when you use the `super.speed` directly in your subclass `Bike`, the compiler will throw:

```
super may not be used on value speed
```

so this compiler error thrown is also caused by the above reason.

Comment: "As we know, after Scala compile, it will transfer to Java bytecode for compatible with JVM." This phrase makes no sense. Did you use google translator?

Comment: @pedrofurla, ;)

Answer (score 4):

Answers to similar questions here [overriding-vals-in-scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309321/overriding-vals-in-scala), or here [cannot-use-super-when-overriding-values](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/10721) say: `Scala compiler does not allow to use super on a val`

Why is that? Discussion in last link above points to: [SI-899](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-899). And the first comment there says following: `it was changed so that traits could override vals to be more uniform with classes`